# How to Add SSL (ACM) to route 53 which is pointing s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have moved a domain from Godaddy to AWS Route 53. Now I have to ADD SSL. For which I am using the AWS certificate manager (ACM). Now I have requested a certificate through  ACM. A CNAME record is added in my route53.

I need help with the next step. Please guide me. And Let me know If I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Step to do** :

1. Create S3 bucket and select website hosting
2. Create CloudFront select S3 origin and select ACM from suggestion.
3. In Route53 map CloudFront against A record of domain.

**Note**: CloudFront origin and CNAME name should match with ACM domain name.

[image]